# Not able to bind to docker container port

Tags: windows, iis, docker

I manage to have Windows Server 2016 and Windows Container installed in my VirtualBox for testing.

I also follow the guide here https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-samples/iis-10.0 to build an image with iis installed.

However I'm not able to bind port 80 from container to any port in the host, here's how I run the container with port mapping and result of **docker ps** command:

[image]

I also try -p switch without explicitly telling the port mapping, but that doesn't work either

I tried to attach to the container and request the default iis web page using **wget** and everything seems fine:

[image]

And here's result of the **docker inspect** the container, in the **exposedports** section, it says port 80/tcp is exported, but not sure why it's not reflected in the host machine. Can someone give me an idea where I go wrong? Or is this a bug from Windows Container? I tried to post in msdn forum but their process of verifying account is really troublesome

https://api.myjson.com/bins/4a1f4

Comment: Hi, did you get this resolved? I have the same issue using docker run with -p and docker ps not showing the ports and connections are not working. In contrast to you I am running on the Azure Windows Server 2016 TP3 image.

Comment: @ikkjo unfortunately I still haven't been able to solve this. After hours of trying without luck, I decided to wait for their official release instead